# Question about bitmap saving in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I have a bitmap object and draw some curves on it by setpixel method. when I save this bitmap as jpg file, the background of my picture is not a white surface. the background is transparent. what is the problem? How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `Graphics.Clear(Color.White)` before you draw on the bitmap.  If you do not already have an instance of `System.Drawing.Graphics` for your bitmap, here's how to get one:

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
```

Clear the bitmap:

```
g.Clear(Color.White);
```

And of course, don't forget to call `Dispose()` when you are done with the graphics.

```
g.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that you are saving the image out in JPEG format?  AFAIK, JPEG doesn't support transparancy, so perhaps you're saving the image out as GIF or PNG with a ".jpg" extension, and your viewer is ignoring the extension.

In any case, Zach's solution should fill your bitmap with a solid background color before you start drawing.

Comment: And your background is *transparent*???  How can that be? Neither BMP or JPG formats support transparency...

Comment: When you create a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, by default all its pixels are transparent.  When you save a `Bitmap` in a format that does not support transparency, the transparent pixels usually end up black.

Comment: @Zach: Yeah, I knew about that. But the OP was saying that the resulting jpg or bmp was transparent: *"when I save this bitmap as jpg file, the background of my picture is not a white surface. the background is transparent"*. That's why I kept trying to clarify...